# How I can produce a png from a tizk tex file (with class standalone)?

Tags: latex, png, pdflatex, tikz

I have the following LaTex file:

```tex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[fill=yellow]{Hello World!};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and I would like to get a single png file from that file. How can I do that?

Many thanks!

PD: I use Ubuntu 22.04

I tried the command convert, online converting but I need something snappy.

Comment: You can find a review of tools to convert a tikz document to png at https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=4461

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have imagemagick installed and compile your document with shell-escape enabled, you can simply use the `convert` option of the standalone class:

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[fill=yellow]{Hello World!};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command in your shell prompt:

```bash
$ pdflatex example.tex && pdftocairo -png example.pdf -r 300 -singlefile
```

This will, of course, produce as well a pdf file.

[image]